# Authorization Token in request header for Rails JSON API DELETE not being recognised

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, http-headers, rails-api

I am putting together a Restful JSON API using rails-api.

I am in the processing of testing my **DELETE** api/v1/users/:id using rspec. I cannot get it to pass when I use an HTTP token as authentication (for the delete action). I  have tested via the terminal and it works but the test wont pass.

Here is the test spec/requests/api/v1/users_spec.rb

```
describe "DELETE api/v1/users/:id" do
it "deletes the requested user" do
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  request_headers = {
    'Authorization' => 'Token token="foobar"'
  }

  delete "api/v1/users/#{user.id}", request_headers

  expect(response.status).to eq 204
 end
end
```

The error I get is `expect 204 got 401.`

In my users_controller.rb I am using this to get the token

```
before_action :authenticate, only: [ :destroy ]
TOKEN = "foobar"

def destroy
   @user = find_user
   @user.destroy
   head 204
end

private

def authenticate
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
    token == TOKEN
  end
end
```

I have also tried the following for setting the authorisation token in the request_headers

```
request_headers = {
    'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' => 'Token token="foobar"'
  }
```

Can anyone point out where I am going wrong or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now solved via this approach:

```
describe "DELETE api/v1/users/:id" do
let(:auth_headers) {
   { 'AUTHORIZATION' => 'Token token="foobar"' }
 }
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  it "deletes the requested user" do

    delete "api/v1/users/#{user.id}", {}, auth_headers

    expect(response.status).to eq 204
  end
end
```

Basically the http headers need to be set in the third parameter. The solution above as passing it as the second so it wasnt getting recognised.